# Can Visual Studio be made to expand type aliases in error messages?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, using, type-alias

Consider the following code with a type error in it. I am trying to return a pointer to double as pointer to int and the intention is that it does not compile. The problem is that the error message is rubbish.

```
template <typename T>
int * Foo(T & t){
    using Bar = T *;
    Bar k = &t;
    return k;
}


int main(){
    double i = 10;
    Foo(i);
   
}
```

The error message from the compiler is [at godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s6Y9EbTY8)

```
example.cpp
<source>(9): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'Bar' to 'int *'
<source>(9): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
<source>(15): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int *Foo<double>(T &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
Compiler returned: 2
```

This drives me nuts because *Bar* tells me nothing about what the problem is as it depends on a template argument. Clang expands the alias in the error message. `aka 'double *'`. See [godbolt again](https://godbolt.org/z/rnfcMo5xE)

```
<source>:9:12: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int *' with an lvalue of type 'Bar' (aka 'double *')
    return k;
           ^
<source>:15:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Foo<double>' requested here
    Foo(i);
    ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Is there a compiler flag or something I can do to make Visual Studio report through the type alias? The annoying thing is that if I inline the type alias I get a decent error message but that precludes writing clean code.

Comment: I've added a fix request against visual studio. Please upvote if you agree. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Please-expand-type-aliases-in-error-mess/1380135?entry=myfeedback